# trying to figure out the layout with background image and section blocks

Tags: html, wordpress, plugins

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUKg3.png)

I tired several methods, but could not achieve the final outcome using several plugins

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more information as to what your desired behavior is?
have you tried using CSS `background-image: url('yourimage.png')`  ?